# it.each used with class member access

Tags: typescript

Often when I'm testing that a particular object/class is wired up correctly, I'll use `it.each` in order to avoid writing a lot of repeated tests. Unfortunately, because the type in question doesn't have an index signature, I have to cast it to any to make it work:

```
class Foo {
    bar = "string"
    baz = "another-string"
}

test.each`
  property  | value
  ${"bar"}  | ${"string"}
  ${"baz"}  | ${"another-string"}
`("$property maps to $value", ({ property, value }) => {

  const foo = new Foo()

  expect((foo as any)[property]).toEqual(value)
});
```

Is there a way of doing this without using any?

Comment: `foo[property as keyof typeof property]` or an if statement to check if it's a key

Comment: That works for me. If you answer with the first one, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of asserting `foo` as `any`, you can assert the key to be a valid key of `foo`:

```
expect(foo[property as keyof typeof foo]).toEqual(value);
```

An if statement could also work:

```
if (property in foo) expect(foo[property]).toEqual(value);
```